# Issue running Flow on Nodejs project

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, flowtype, flow-typed

I am just starting with Flow and I constantly get a crash when I try to run flow with the following error messages:

```sh
(35482) merge_job THROWS: [1] /nodejs-flow/package.json: Parsing_heaps_exceptions.Sig_requires_not_found("/nodejs-flow/package.json")
Raised at file "hashtbl.ml", line 194, characters 13-28
Called from file "src/heap/sharedMem.ml", line 683, characters 24-44


[2020-10-01 13:09:33.888] First merge internal error:
"/nodejs-flow/package.json": (0, 0) to (0, 0)
uncaught exception: Parsing_heaps_exceptions.Sig_requires_not_found("/nodejs-flow/package.json"

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! nodejs-flow@1.0.0 flow:check: `flow check ./src/`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the nodejs-flow@1.0.0 flow:check script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /**/.npm/_logs/2020-10-01T11_09_33_974Z-debug.log
```

this is the content of my flowconfig:

```sh
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/.*

[include]

[libs]
flow-typed

[lints]

[options]
all=true

[strict]
```

For the setup I ran `flow init`, then I installed `flow-typed` globally and ran a `flow-typed install`
I just ran `flow check ./src/` on my code and though I get it sometimes to print out the errors I consistently get the above error code.

Comment: Any reason to ignore package.json and package-lock.json? Doesn't seem necessary. Not sure if it's related to your failure

Comment: No reason, I removed that and it does not change anything, but what does change is when I remove the options, I see less errors...

Comment: That's because the all option runs flow against every file, not just those with @flow defined. Personally I never recommend `all` option. It's usually easier and more standard to just add @flow to all your typed files.

Comment: Thanks it worked better, but I still have this type of error:
`Error: nodejs-flow@1.0.0 flow:check: `flow check ./src/``, and node exited with error code 2, that does not seem like normal behavior, or is it for Flow-Type ?

Comment: Need to see the flow error to provide more help. Can you create a small repro and myself or anyone else could have a look?